# Using German umlauts while opening a url through php

Tags: php, string, http, character-encoding, diacritics

I have written a php code in which i want to access a particular url using a string($password here) that can contain german umlauts like ä,ö,ü.
The code is running perfectly with normal characters but when i use these characters in the string, it is not correctly accessing the url.
For clarification, if I access the url directly through the browser along with the umlaut character string, it is giving expected result.
The following is my code snippet:

`$username='abcd';
$password='abcdä';
$minecraftSocket=fopen("http://login.minecraft.net/user=$username&password=$password&version=13", "rb");`

How should pass the $password to this url so that it gives me the expected result?

Comment: The values can be url encoded (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), but the big issue here is sending a password by URL query string on a non-secure connection.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Pudge601 .Its working now.
And I am aware of the non-secure connection but I have no choice as this is the only way of checking minecraft.net's account which I require to embed in my script.
Thanks anyways.